# Reloading JWPlayer after video completes

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

At the moment the code I'm working with is reloading the entire page when a video ends.  It utilizes the onComplete event, verifies the video completed was my video and not an ad, then executes window.location to reload the page.

I'm wandering if there is a more efficient way to do this... instead of reloading the whole page just provide jwplayer with the next video to play as well a new tag in ova-jw: ads: schedule:.  The existing setup just seems very inefficient.

I think that it was originally setup to reload the entire page because new video info and  ad tag is obtained before the jwplayer is loaded.  But, I'm thinking it would be more efficient to use ajax to obtain info for next video and ad and just update the jwplayer with what to play/do next.

Thank you,
Kate

Comment: You could always use onComplete, then execute another jwplayer().setup(), instead of reloading the page.

Comment: Thanks again Ethan :)  I was just reading through http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28842/working-with-playlists/ and thought I would load the jwplayer with "'autostart':false," then call the loadVideo function (as illustrated in the link) from onComplete.